# Start `RemoteWebDriver` server separately from creating a `webdriver.Remote` instance?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Using the Selenium Python bindings, is it possible to start the `RemoteWebDriver` server separately from creating a `webdriver.Remote` instance?  The point of doing this would be to save time spent repeatedly starting and stopping the server when all I really need is a new instance of the client. (This is possible with ChromeDriver.)

Comment: the server is started independently.  creating an instance of webdriver.Remote does not start the server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you re-post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the server is started independently. creating an instance of `webdriver.Remote` does not start the server.

Comment: One comment I'd like to make because of your concern of starting/stopping a browser.  I usually keep one browser open during the duration of tests and in my setUp and TearDown methods driver.get("about:blank"), and if you want to clear all cookies and cache, if necessary too.  I find this really speeds up test runs because starting/stopping browsers/setting profiles, depending on the load on the client takes several seconds